# Rails Asset Pipeline: What happens when we do require in application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to contribute to the opensource project jquery-datatables-rails. But it puzzles me as how it works. I have basic understanding of how to create gem. It seems like the project just simplifies the path references but nothing more. The four steps listed to install are

```
Add to the assets group in your Gemfile:

gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'

Install the gem:

bundle install

Add the JavaScript to application.js:

//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables

Add the stylesheets to application.css:

*= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

But I don't understand how Rails knows where to find dataTables folder and why we use jquery.dataTables to reference the file/class. The code is easy to understand, but the file organization confuses me so much. Is there any writing on topics related to my confusion?
Thanks.

**Update:**
Just found this great documentation on Rails Engine: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Rails asset pipeline searches for the files in `app/assets/`, `lib/assets`, and `vendor/assets` of the Rails application. But this gem is a Rails engine, and it adds path of its own assets to default assets paths. It has its own [vendor/assets](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets).